# Realtime - incoming call data & call complete data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've been trying to use Subscription to get callRecords to see if I can do a on hangup call to action.

But subscriptions are too delayed to make sense. I need on call end immediately notify.

Also I want to be able to get a incoming call's phone number before answering the call not after the call is completed.

What I've tried:

```
  //Issue this is very slow, the call ends and the endpoint receives data 15 minutes later.
  var subscription = new Subscription
        {
            ChangeType = "created,updated",
            NotificationUrl = "https://myendpoint.com",
            Resource = "/communications/callRecords",
            ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(6)
        };

        await graphClient.Subscriptions.Request()
            .AddAsync(subscription);
        var subscriptions = await graphClient.Subscriptions
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();
```

Comment: You can subscribe to change notification to get the CallEnded event notification.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT See edit, I've subscribed to call record but it's very slow. We are looking for a more real time solution

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other way to get the realtime CallEnded event.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any other way to get the realtime CallEnded event.